# How i can sort histogram bar in ascending/descending order of seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I want to get only top 15 values in sorted order from histogram of seaborn to display.

[opening_loc['City'] contains various city name with some repeated city in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Ohw.png)

```
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,6))
    ax = sns.histplot(data=opening_loc['City'], color="green" )
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(f'{p.get_height():.0f}', (p.get_x()+0.5, p.get_height()), ha='center', va='bottom', color='Red')
```

Comment: Your question needs more clarification! Please, take a look at "How to Ask A Good Question" (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It can help you to enhance your question.

Comment: No screenshots of code please.

Comment: You seem to call `histplot` while you want a `countplot`

Comment: @JohanC i almost getting same thing i.e. still unsort. If i use `Countplot` in place `histplot` how to sort that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas, use `data = opening_loc['City'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)[0:15]`

Comment: No, this is not working it is sorting according to alphabets order,  i want to sort them with number of occurrences. @kal

Comment: Edited the answer. Use value_counts to count number of occurrences and then sort. Also, please post your code instead of screenshots. You will get responses a lot faster

Comment: When you do your own counting, maybe a barplot is more adequate than a histplot?

Comment: @kal thanks for tips i am new in stack overflow so needs to explore some tools in it. your code still didn't worked. but thanks for idea of `value_counts` i helped to get my result. @JohanC thanks for correcting me i tired with `barplot` and `countplot` it help me to get what i wanted.